# Sorting multiple lists with another sorted list?

Tags: java, list

Yeah I know, the title doesn't really mean much.
This is what I am trying to do:

> Banana | 3
>
> Pineapple | 2
>
> Apple | 1

I get this output from printing different lists with `[list].get(i) + "|" + [anotherList].get(i)`

Now, I want to sort `[list]` by alphabetical order, while maintaining the other list linked to it

This should be the expected output:

> Apple | 1
>
> Banana | 3
>
> Pineapple | 2

How can I do so? Obviously I am not having trouble in sorting the list itself, I have trouble maintaining everything together. Also I have way more lists than 2 (they are not shown here).

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Ditch the lists, make objects that encapsulate the elements at the index `i`.

Comment: @Savior How do I do that?

Comment: `new NumberedFruit(list.get(i), anotherList.get(i), evenMore.get(i));`, then sort a list of those.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `HashMap` for your `list` items. The keys will be the `list` items and the corresponding values will be entries from other lists. For example, you have 3 lists. These are `list`, `anotherList` and `anotherList2`.

First you set the values properly which are associated with the `list` keys. Declare a `HashMap` first for this.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Now populate the data in your map like this.

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> otherItems = new ArrayList<>();
    otherItems.add(anotherList.get(i));
    otherItems.add(anotherList2.get(i));
    map.put(list.get(i), otherItems);
}
```

Now simply sort the `list` for getting the fruits sorted alphabetically and hence get the corresponding values associated with it from those two different lists by searching them in the `HashMap`.

```
list.get(i) + "|" + getValuesSeperatedWithABar(map.get(list.get(i)))
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: This should work. How can I access the single values though? I need to get the value for each entry.

Comment: The value in the `HashMap` is another list which you need to traverse to get the items stored inside. This is what you should do inside `getValuesSeperatedWithABar` method.